# Filter queryset by subquery on two conditions

Tags: python, django

I need to filter SomeModel queryset on max date by groups (user field). The Model looks like:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    ...
```

I've already created some kind of subquery:

```
from django.db.models import Max

subquery = (SomeModel.objects
            .all()
            .values('user')
            .annotate(latest_date=Max('date')))
```

So I want to use this subquery to filter SomeModel queryset on two conditions:

```
# pseudocode 

SomeModel.objects.filter(user==subquery.user and time==subquery.latest_time)
```

Is it possible at all or my approach is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the result I wanted to get could be achieved this way:

```
SomeModel.objects.order_by('user', 'date').distinct('user')
```

It's not an answer on initial question but it could help someone.